# Data is not getting set in php when ajax call is successful

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php file Filter page.php, where I am making the ajax call and also writing the logic
The alert on success shows the correct data but when I am trying to echo the same in php, it is showing nothing

```
<html>

<body>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['grpNm'])){
  echo $_POST['grpNm'];
  var_dump($_POST['grpNm']);

}

?>
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

     var GrpNm="ABC";
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "FilterPage.php",
         data: {grpNm : GrpNm},
         success: function(data){ 
           alert(data);
                  },
         error: function(data){ 
           alert("No"); 
                  },
                  
                });
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is showing nothing"? Did you check the output? Also, why do you dump AJAX related output in the middle of the other HTML markup?

Comment: As I have kept the echo statement in if clause, so the variable is not getting set and echo statement doesn't work and gives no output whereas while I alert the data in ajax success call, it is showing the data correctly. And do we need to separate the ajax call from html ?? I am doing the same and it was working before

Comment: If it was working before, what did you change?

Comment: The same type of code I did few years back and in different machine .and it was working and I am doing same ajax call and posting in php but not working..

Comment: If you are using the **same** code, and sometimes it's working, and sometimes it's not, you need to check why this is happening. For example, have a look at your browser's network console to see whether the request is sent as expected.

Comment: Yes the request is going, it is showing in network.

Comment: Then go on debugging. Does the request contain all data as expected? Does the response look like the one you would expect?